# Using PHP substr function to crop sentence

Tags: php, string, formatting, str-replace, substr

I have the string **1. Welcome**.

I'd like to split the string into 2 strings: **1** & **Welcome**.

How would I use **substr** PHP function to achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular case, the most appropriate function would be [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$str = '1. Welcome';
$parts = explode('. ', $str);

// explode returns a numerically indexed array, so:
$number = $parts[0];
$title = $parts[1];
```

You can combine this with the [`list`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) construct for extra convenience:

```
list($number, $title) = explode('. ', $str);
```

Finally, it's a good idea to specify the third parameter of `explode` (limit to how many tokens are generated) in case the title contains dots:

```
list($number, $title) = explode('. ', $str, 2);
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, Jon. Many, many thanks. I always seem to forget about explode. Appreciate your detailed reply here.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php is the most comprehensive answer you'll get.

If you want to split the string that way I'd recommend using the `explode` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, though.